# How to fix Issue with PyAudio in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyaudio, portaudio

I tried installing Pyaudio in Python but Python says it requires Portaudio binding for the installation.Help me fix this please.My platform is Windows.I am using Python 3.7.2.

I did:

1.I followed the instructions provided in the portaudio website and generated dll file using visual studio.

The portaudio directory where the compiled files are located is my Desktop.

[image: Screenshot 7]

2.Anyway I have installed pyaudio using a setup(exe) file which i found somewhere.

So whenever i type the command "pip install pyaudio", it says the requirements are already fulfilled.

But when i use the alternative command "easy_install pyaudio",it shows an error related to portaudio.

[image: Screenshot 8]

3.And whenever I run a python file which uses pyaudio it again says binding is required.

[image: Screenshot 9]

So, I need the solution to bind Portaudio files which are in my desktop with python.

I searched everywhere for the solution but since I am a beginner, all the tutorials provided in different websites were hard to understand for me.

So please help me with a simple and descriptive solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ouch, it seems like you have chosen a painful way to get pyaudio installed.
I never compile on windows, if I can't find a pre-compiled binary I will look around for a different way to get to where I want to (different library…)

you can uninstall with `pip uninstall pyaudio`

anyways, here's one way to get it working.

- download and install a "miniconda" (google if you don't know what it is)
- do `conda install pyaudio` in your "conda"-prompt

I did not truly check the install, but I did the conda install… and it would have installed both portaudio and pyaudio so I suppose it will work.